# "number of people purchasing X" vs "number of people who purchase X"

Tags: american-english, modifiers

I'm confused between

a) "number of people purchasing plane tickets" *vs.*
  b) "number of people who purchase plane tickets"

Is a) okay to use if number of people purchasing tickets is increasing vs people who only buy the tickets online?

Comment: The difference in meaning between (a) and (b) has nothing to do with whether purchases were made online.

Comment: @A.Ellett I think he's asking which would be used when it's part of a comparison. Purchasing online is just an example of the comparison being made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case they are equivalent.

However, note that "purchasing" must be used when referring to the continuous or incomplete action like:

> He is purchasing tickets at the counter.
>
> There are many people purchasing tickets now.

Comment: Thanks for the comments I get it now, 'a)' says in general number of people purchasing online ticket and 'b)' just focuses on people who buys online ticket so the comparison is between general population and online airline ticket buyers. Mainly I was trying to understand the meaning.